# Implementing Readiness and Liveness probe in Azure AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I am trying to follow this documentation to enable readiness and liveness probe on my pods for health checkes in my cluster, however it gives me an error where connection refused to the container IP and port. Portion where i have added the readiness and liveness is below.

I am using helm for deployment and the port i am trying to monitor is 80. The service file for ingress is also given below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-add-health-probes

Service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: expose-portal 
annotations:
service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "{{ .Values.isInternal }}"
spec:
type: LoadBalancer
ports:
- port: 80
selector:
app: portal
```

Deployment.yaml

```
    spec:
  containers:
  - name: App-server-portal
    image: myacr-app-image-:{{ .Values.image_tag }}
    imagePullPolicy: Always      
    ports:
    - name: http
      containerPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
    readinessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /
        port: 80
      periodSeconds: 3
      timeoutSeconds: 1
    livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /
        port: 80
      periodSeconds: 3
      timeoutSeconds: 1
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/nginx
      readOnly: true
      name: mynewsite
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: my-secret
  volumes:
  - name: mynewsite.conf
    configMap:
      name: mynewsite.conf
      items:
      - key: mynewsite.conf
        path: mynewsite.conf
```

Am i doing something wrong here. As per azure documentation as of today Probing on a port other than the one exposed on the pod is currently not supported. My understanding is that port 80 on my pod is already exposed.

Comment: well, does your app actually listen on port 80? does it return 20x HTTP code?

Comment: Well let me explain. I am not sure on the below statement that as per azure documentation says
"Probing on a port other than the one exposed on the pod is currently not supported."

My service listens to port 80 inside the container. However externally its accessible only via my ingress service which is Azure load balancer.

When i implement this health check what i notice is that the health checks are trying to connect to the internal IP of the container and NOT LB ip or the Node ip. So is this how it works?

Is that the reason why connection refuses to container port?

Comment: well, you have port 80 exposed and you probe on port 80. that one is fine, but does you pod actually work as it should without liveness\readiness probe?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Yes it works when i call my Private ip of the LB in browser or when i curl it i am getting an output and 200 status code. The only thing is when i introduce the probe and the describe my pod, the liveness or rediness status says my xx.xx.xx.xx:80 (private ip of container) connection refused. :(

Comment: increase timeout value, perhaps? no idea. i dont see anything wrong with this yaml

Comment: Okay thanks. That makes sense. I will try and get back. Thanks lot

Comment: Thanks 4c74 it indeed worked when i changed the readiness timeout as periodSeconds: 180
      timeoutSeconds: 3. Reason was that the loadbalancer takes more than 2 minutes to come live and receive traffic.

However i am still not clear with the terminologies periodSeconds and timeoutSeconds. My understanding was that periodSeconds is the number of times readiness will be checked with an interval of timeoutSeconds. Can you give please me a clear idea of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

taken from the docs:

1. initialDelaySeconds: Number of seconds after the container has started before liveness or readiness probes are initiated. Defaults to 0 seconds. Minimum value is 0.
2. periodSeconds: How often (in seconds) to perform the probe. Default to 10 seconds. Minimum value is 1.
3. timeoutSeconds: Number of seconds after which the probe times out. Defaults to 1 second. Minimum value is 1.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#configure-probes

The solution was to increase timeout.

PS. I think you might need to introduce `initialDelaySeconds` instead of increasing timeout to 3 minutes